# File system info - date created on THIS computer

Tags: filesystems, operating-system

Not sure which forum this goes under.

For some time I've found it hindering, and often annoying, that no common filesystem or OS stores what would be a third timestamp on files and folders in addition to creation and modification date.  That is the timestamp of when that file was created/copied/came into existance through any means, on the current computer.  It seems like a tiny amount of extra data, and can be set to read-only after the file completes its creation.

This would make uninstalling programs easier, dealing with viruses, finding lost files when you forget where they were saved to, and I'm sure would have many more uses.

Has this ever been attempted?  Are there reasons not to implement this in future OSes or file systems?  (Without getting into debates about how mobile operating systems are hiding files from users more and more)

Does this already exist and I'm just ignorant of how to view this detail on files in Unix systems etc.?

Comment: Isn't that just the creation date?

Comment: Really the problem is is it is simple to change the system time, which would render this just as useless as any other date

Comment: @Mehrdad The creation date is when it was created.  As soon as I copy that file to another computer I no longer know when it was created locally.

Comment: @user1428799 That's the case with the creation and modification dates, so I don't see how it's an argument against adding a "local creation" date

Comment: @FaultyJuggler: Say I have a 1 GB file, and a year later, I resize it to 1 byte. Then I pad it to 1 MB. What should your proposed creation date be?

Comment: @Mehrdad that file would forever have the timestamp of when it was created at 1 GB on that computer, the only time this "local" timestamp changes is in a move to a new computer.  You did just make me wonder about moving between filesystems, say a second hard drive.  So perhaps it should more be "creation date on this device."  This could make things interesting for systems like dropbox, but since the files are copies on the machines perhaps it wouldn't matter.  That is assuming that it's copy on the server is handled differently.  I noticed dropbox does not save the meta file from OSX folders.

Comment: @FaultyJuggler: The problem is more difficult than you realize, for a variety of reasons... such as [NTFS tunneling](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/07/15/439261.aspx). Also notice that file systems do NOT have a concept of "what device" they're on... there can be a million layers between the storage device and the file system. The storage device might be in RAM, or over the network, or on a virtual disk, etc... really, it's not as simple as you think.

Comment: @Mehrdad That's a complexity if we assume the timestamp should be set by storage device.  All of that goes away if we handle this "local" creation date at the OS level.  The OS knows when the first time it has possession of a file is, either during copy or creation.  Both of these actions start and end in the OS regardless of source or destination. Even in the case of sending a file either the other OS is receiving it, or I am accessing a drive directly such as shared or network, but that local timestamp is still valid.

Answer (score 0):

Short of mucking with the system time or otherwise changing the kernel, you already have a way of obtaining a guaranteed upper bound on when a file was changed in any way under POSIX: `st_ctime`, the inode change time. With the `utime()` system call, user processes can set whatever values they want for `st_mtime` (the modification time) and `st_atime` (the access time), but `st_ctime` always gets the current time. It's not possible to "backdate" a file's last change time.